# How does CfsSubsetEva (Correlation-based Feature Selection) works in Weka

Tags: weka, categorical-data, feature-selection, imbalanced-data, pearson-correlation

I have a dataset which is categorical dataset. I am using `WEKA` software for feature selection. I have used `CfsSubsetEval` as attribute evaluator with Greedystepwise method. I came to know [this link](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/publications/1997/Hall-LSmith97.pdf) that CFS uses `Pearson correlation` to find the strong correlation between the dataset. I also found out how to calculate Pearson correlation coefficient using [this link](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-calculate-a-correlation/). As per the link the data values need to be numerical for evaluation.  **Then how can WEKA did the evaluation on my categorical dataset?**

The strange result is that Among 70 attributes CFS selects only 10 attributes. Is it because of the categorical dataset? Additionally my dataset is a highly imbalanced dataset where imbalanced ration 1:9(yes:no).

**A Quick question**

If you go through the [link](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-calculate-a-correlation/) you can found the statement  `the correlation coefficient to measure the strength and direction of the linear relationship between two numerical variables X and Y.` Now I can understand the strength of the correlation coefficient which is varied in between +1 to -1 but what about the direction? How can I get that? I mean the variable is not a vector so it should not have a direction.

Answer (score 0):

The method [correlate](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/attributeSelection/CfsSubsetEval.java#L748) in the CfsSubsetEval class is used to compute the correlation between two attributes. It calls other methods, depending on the attribute types, which I've linked here:

- two numeric attributes: [num_num](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/attributeSelection/CfsSubsetEval.java#L923)
- numeric/nominal attributes: [num_nom2](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/attributeSelection/CfsSubsetEval.java#L963)
- two nominal attributes: [nom_nom](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/attributeSelection/CfsSubsetEval.java#L1080)